# How to not to rotate a certain UIView allowing UIViewController's rotation

Tags: ios, uiview, camera, rotation

Does anyone know fix(not to rotate) a certain UIView with allowing rotation of UIViewController?

I want to implement a interface like camera app UI. A view showing camera's view does not rotate but HUD(like buttons) does rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply transformation to the view you don't want to rotate.
Use following method to do it.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI/2);
    }
    else if(interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft)
    {
        view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    } 
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your very quick reply! it was a great help!